# Cakephp redirection problem

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, cakephp-1.3

I have a problem of too many redirection in one cakephp site.

Here is the site: http://pexinxas24.com/

This domain is pointed to root of the site and not to app folder.

Here is the code which is placed in htaccess of the root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /app/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Here is the code which is places in the htaccess of the app folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /app/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

I am not getting any typs of PHP or cakephp errors.

This site always redirect to the root of the site. Whole code was working properly on old server. I have just changed the server and getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your are using Amazon-EC2 right? ;)

Well, probably you aren't redirected for the next reasons:

1. **mod_rewrite it isn't enabled**: Look inside of your httpd.conf, you should have the next line uncommented:

   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
2. **You haven't enabled override in htaccess**: Look inside of your http.conf for the
   directive "Directory", inside you should have something like this:

   ```
       <Directory "/var/www/html">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
       </Directory>
   ```

   The most important line of the previous code is **AllowOverride All**, on amazon instances is set to AllowOverride none by default, so you should change it to **All**, after that **you must restart your apache server** to reflect changes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled which I can see from the phpinfo().

Comment: check your http.con file then, i'm almost sure that your file doesn't have an AllowOverride All option as i mentionated earlier. hope that helps.

Comment: it dependes of your distro, but you usually use vim or nano linux editors (nano its the easiest). Generic steps are like the next ones:


Once you are logged in the system, switch to root, then:
vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
then use the editor to edit the directive i mentioned earlier.
finally restart the apache:  /etc/init.d/httpd restart 
cross fringers and see if the change works, it's not rocket science to perform all this steps.

Comment: I found that it's not just the .htaccess file, but also the virtual host directive for /var/www in apache.conf that had an AllowOverride none.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread. 
Probably if you understand about apache2 Ismael's answer is quite enough, but if you're a newbe in this subject as I am, might be useful saying that in apache2 nowadays you should **"replace"** the part one where he says

> mod_rewrite it isn't enabled: Look inside of your httpd.conf, you should have the next line uncommented: **LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**

for **copying *rewrite.load* from *mods-available* to *mods-enabled*:**

> cp /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load